# R: Rank cells in a list of matrices based on cell position

Tags: r, matrix, rank

I have a list of matrices containing association measurements between GPS tracked animals. One matrix in the list is observed association rates, the others are association rates for randomized versions of the GPS tracking trajectories. For example, I currently have 99 permutations of randomized tracking trajectories resulting in a list of 99 animal association matrices, plus the observed association matrix. I am expecting that for the animals that belong to the same pack, the observed association rates will be higher than the randomized association rates. Accordingly, I would like to determine the rank of the observed rates compared to the randomized rates for each dyad (cell). Essentially, I am doing a rank-permutation test. However, since I am only really concerned with determining if the observed association data is greater than the randomized trajectory association data, any result just giving the rank of the observed cells is sufficient.

```
ls <- list(matrix(10:18,3,3), matrix(18:10,3,3))
```

I've seen using sapply can get the ranks of particular cells. Could I do the following for all cells and take the final number in the resulting vector to get the rank of the cell in that position in the list (knowing the position of the observed data in the list of matrices, e.g. last).

```
rank(sapply(ls, '[',1,1))
```

The ideal result would be a matrix of the same form as those in the list giving the rank of the observed data, although any similar solutions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To make sure I've wrapped my head around what you want: for your example data, you'd want a 3x3 matrix populated with 1 and 2 to indicate whether each entry was 1st or 2nd in the ranking of it versus its match in the other mtarix? Also, what would you like done with ties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* proceed that way, but there are cleaner and quicker methods to get what you want.

Here's some code that would take your `ls` produce a 3x3 matrix with the following properties:

- if the entry in `ls[[1]]` is greater than the corresponding entry of `ls[[2]]`, record a 1
- if the entry in `ls[[1]]` is less than the corresponding entry of `ls[[2]]`, record a 2
- if the entries are equal, record a 1.5

```
result <- 1 * (ls[[1]] > ls[[2]]) + 2 * (ls[[1]] < ls[[2]]) + 1.5 * (ls[[1]] == ls[[2]])
```

How it works: when we do something like `ls[[1]] > ls[[2]]`, we are ripping out the matrices of interest and directly comparing them. The result of this bit of code is a `T`/`F`-populated matrix, which is secretly coded as a `0`/`1` matrix. We can then multiply it by whatever coefficient we want to represent that situation.

Comment: Before I close the question Aaron, I've edited my question to add a bit more detail, here is what I actually did to solve my problem:

randnets[[100]] <- obsnet #add observed association matrix to list of randomized
maxnet <- apply(simplify2array(randnets), 1:2, max) #get the max cell of the list of matricies
ranknet <- 1*(obsnet<maxnet)+2*(obsnet==maxnet) #need to add a zero where assoc. =0
ranknet[which(obsnet + maxnet == 0)] = 0 #set to zero where there are no contacts in both randomized and observed assoc. rates

Is editing your response or my question neccessary? Thanks again

Comment: The standard for whether an edit is required is something like: would a third party who stumbles on this question in 5 years see enough in the post as is to recreate a working solution? So if you feel like there's something novel in your additional code that you'd like preserved for that viewer, an edit makes sense. (For my money, I think everything that third user would need is already here before any edits, but it's totally your call.)